# On basic functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $T$ is right shift operator on $l^{2}\mathbb(N)$, $A$ is bounded operator on $l^{2}\mathbb(N)$ and $||A-T||<1$, prove that $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need to show what you have tried or where you are stuck in order to get immediate feedbacks.

Comment: Some information I got from the conditions are (i) since set of invertible elements in Banach algebra form an open set so if A is invertible then there exists neighbourhood around A where all elements are invertible, but problem is pushing T in the neighbourhood to get the contradiction, (ii) A is bounded below and range of A is closed from the conditions

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is invertible, then $Ay=(1,0,\ldots)$ for some $y \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Thus $(A-T)y = (1,y_1,y_2,\ldots)$ and $\|(A-T)y\|^2=1+\|y\|^2$. Why we must have $\|A-T\| \geq 1$?

Comment: Thanks to P4sch